# File download issue, getting login page instead of actual file

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, download

Trying to download file using HttpWebRequest and response object.
Instead of actual file the response returns HTML of the login screen.

Here is my code:

```
int bytesToRead = 10000;

// Buffer to read bytes in chunk size specified above
byte[] buffer = new Byte[bytesToRead];
string Url = "https://myurl/filename.pdf";
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
HttpWebRequest fileReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Url);
fileReq.Timeout = 1000000;
fileReq.KeepAlive = true;

string userID= "emailid";
string Password= "password";



//string credentials = "emailid:password";
//fileReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(credentials)));

fileReq.PreAuthenticate = true;

fileReq.Headers.Add("user", userID);
fileReq.Headers.Add("pass", Password);

//CredentialCache wrCache =
//              new CredentialCache();
//wrCache.Add(new Uri(Url), "Basic",
//  new NetworkCredential(userID, Password));
//fileReq.Credentials = wrCache;

//Create a response for this request
HttpWebResponse fileResp = (HttpWebResponse)fileReq.GetResponse();              



if (fileReq.ContentLength > 0)
    fileResp.ContentLength = fileReq.ContentLength;                


string resultString = string.Empty;
using (Stream rstream = fileResp.GetResponseStream())
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(rstream))
    {
        rstream.Flush();
        resultString = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

resultString,  is the HTML of login page of website in which the pdf file reside.

I have tried several approaches(commented in above code) for passing user id and password, none worked.

I am able to download the file directly using URL in browser with same user id and password

Comment: If you're seeing a login window, then it's likely some form of cookie authentication, and you can't simply do BASIC authentication. Instead, send a request that posts to the login form and obtains the login cookie, then provide that cookie when you go to download the file.

Comment: @Bananna, by "directly using URL" i mean I am using "https://myurl/filename.pdf" this as URL it opens the login screen where i enter userid and password then the file gets downloaded properly

Comment: @mason,  can you provide me some links which explains how to do what you mentioned?

Comment: It should be straightforward. Inspect the HTTP traffic between client and server in your browser. Note the names of the field that get submitted during login and look at the cookies received. Then emulate that in your code. If you get stuck on a specific part of your implementation, then post your attempt and explain what's wrong with it.